# iOS CoreData Migration using Custom Mapping Models with multiple historical database versions

Tags: ios, core-data

I have an app and many history versions of the database.
Our users are typically "once in a year" users, so this means you can never be sure which version of the database their app is running on.

Now in my new version of the database I need to do some custom migration.
The method I use to do this is described in this tutorial: http://9elements.com/io/index.php/customizing-core-data-migrations/

To summarize: I have to make Custom Mapping Models so that I can write my own migration policies for some fields.

Now when I create a Custom Mapping Model, I have to select a Source "xcdatamodel" and a Destination "xcdatamodel" (where "destination" is te new version of my database).

My question is, if I want to do this custom migration from all possible versions, do I need to create multiple Custom Mapping Models, all with a different source, or is there a smarter way to do this?
Or is CoreData smart enough to recognize this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is yes; you need to test every migration from every source model to your current destination model.  If that migration requires a custom mapping then you will need to have a mapping for that pair.

Core Data does not understand versions; it only understands source and destination.  If there is not a way to get from A to B then it will fail.  If it can migrate from A to B automatically and you have the option turned on, then it will.  Otherwise a heavy (manual) migration is required.

Keep in mind that heavy migrations are VERY labor intensive and I strictly recommend avoiding them.  I have found it is far more efficient to export (for example to JSON) and import the data back in then it is to do a heavy migration.

Answer (score 0):

It is enough to have a consistent sequential series of migration models up to the current version. Core Data is "smart" enough to execute the migrations you tell it to migrate in the given order.

Comment: that is incorrect unfortunately.  Core Data has no concept of sequence.  It only knows source and destination.  It will not execute more than one migration.

Comment: Thanks, Marcus, I amended the answer. Of course, it is not automatic.